# html5/css- Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: css, html, validation

in my html document, i have with `<div class="text">` formated place for text block, where are some lists(ordered/unordered) but validator found error:
Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

what should i change? class text is formated in css and is used on every subpage.
changing to `<p>` or `<article>` didnt help to validate.

thx4help

*edit-not article but div

Comment: Please provide your generated HTML markup so we can see the error and advise.

Comment: `li` can only be children of a `ul` and no other children of a `ul` are allowed.

Comment: im new in html so idk what you mean,but i hope this is it:
Line 98, Column 16: Element li not allowed as child of element article in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
<li class="ul1">SATA, SATA2, SATA3 (Serial Advanced Technology Attachment)</li>
Contexts in which element li may be used:
Inside ol elements.
Inside ul elements.
Inside menu elements whose type attribute is in the toolbar state.
Content model for element article:
Flow content.

Comment: @Paulie_D to be correct, `li` can be a child of a `ul` **or** an `ol`

Answer (score 6):

An

```
<li>
```

element always has to be inside an

```
<ul> or <ol>
```

like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

`ul` is an unordered list, while `ol` is an ordered list.

Comment: i know,but thats not my problem, i need to change type of that text box in which that lists are: pic: http://i58.tinypic.com/ke65xv.jpg

Comment: In that case your error is somewhere else, maybe you forgot to close a div or something similar